# Message queue IPC implementation on Linux

Tags: perl, message-queue

I have a multi-processed perl system that picks up a lot of files ( may be in 10 Millions ) and works on the them one by one

Since each process must pick up exclusive files I need to have one seperate process that does the file-listing and sends the filenames to a message queue

Each worker-process will query the message-queue , get 10 jobs at a time and execute the 10 jobs until the message-queue is empty

What is the best way of implementing a message queue

Comment: [Gearman](http://p3rl.org/Gearman::XS), [TheSchwartz](http://p3rl.org/TheSchwartz), [Qudo](http://p3rl.org/Qudo)

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Queue::Beanstalk](http://search.cpan.org/~lunatic/Queue-Beanstalk-0.02/lib/Queue/Beanstalk.pm) a try.

Answer (score 1):

I'd vote for [Net::RabbitMQ](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aRabbitMQ) and [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)